# Прилагательное путейный

Tags: синонимы

Путейный - относящийся к железной дороге. Есть путейные рабочие = путейщики, есть улицы Путейные возле любого вокзала, есть домкраты путейные многотонные, смотрители путейные есть и ходят они в путейных оранжевых жилетах.
Но слова такого нет ни в одном словаре! В чем тут дело? Не хватает частоты словоупотребления или чего-то еще...
Зато есть слово *путейский*, но мне оно кажется слегка устаревшим и не отражающим всю гамму значений.
Хотелось бы узнать мнение форума.

> Евгений Чубаров. Чеченские призывники займутся спортом (2001) // «Известия», 2001.11.23  Там им предстоит стать экскаваторщиками, бульдозеристами или **путейными рабочими**.

Comment: > Есть путейные рабочие = путейщики,

В орфографическом словаре — *путеец*, а *путейщик* отсутствует. 

Comment: Вот и я о том же)  
> Дубичева Ксения. СТОП, КРАН! // Труд-7, 2005.08.23 А недавно **путейщики** рассказали, что пути проложат через наши огороды.  

Допустим, путейцы - обслуживают ж/д пути, а путейщики - их прокладывают. Должна же быть хоть какая-то дифференциация)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

По той же причине, по которым в словарях нет слова "миксер" в значении бетоновоз, хотя как минимум в Вологде, люди связанные со строительством, и водители автобетономешалок по другому данную машину не называют.

У меня в очень много знакомых на железной дороге (Северная и Октябрьская ж\д), но слова "путейный" от них никогда не слышал. Домкраты и пр. называют **путевЫми**. Другое наименование обходчиков - **путеец**, правда "путейщик" тоже попадалось в речи, хоть и значительно реже.

Comment: Тем не менее, редкие слова (формы слов) должны фиксироваться в словарях. Есть путевой, а есть путёвый, значительная разница в значении. Также путевой и путейный. Первое имеет широкое применение (путевой лист, путевой маршрут), второе исключительно относится к ж/д вопросам.

Comment: Если будет издаваться словарь железнодорожного жаргона, слова "путейный" и "путейщик" там наверняка будут, в противном случае в фиксации особой необходимости нет.

Comment: Зачем тогда фиксировать всякие там флэшки? Слово флэшка разговорное и иностранного происхождения, а путейный - вполне русское, с русским суффиксом (литейный, питейный, кофейный) и всероссийским ж/д значением.  
![Путейный](http://dozastroy.ru/6_1.jpg)

Comment: Разговорную лексику фиксируют, а диалектизмы, жаргонизмы и прочую специальную лексику только в специализированных словарях. Вас ведь не сильно растраивает отсутствие в словарях общего значения такого глагола как "полёгать" (взвесить рукой), хотя лично я такое слово слышал неоднократно.

Comment: А про магазин что скажете, дескать, жаргонным словом назван? Крепко сомневаюсь...

Comment: А магазины теперь только филологи открывают? мне с фирмой КонкретИнвестВосток приходилось дело иметь, так что я по отношению к предприятиям ни в чём не сомневаюсь.

Comment: Я думаю, название магазина "Путейный" никого из знающих русский язык не приведет врасплох. А что там с филологами и предприятиями? не врубился, прошу извинить.